# Can a clone be in sync with its original user when it is still active?

Tags: naruto

In manga, chapter 647, I saw that First Hokage's wood clone was able hear the discussion between original (Edo-Tensei) Hashirama and Madara Uchiha. Is this possible?

I have seen that Yamato's wood clone was **not** able to communicate with his original, that's why he was using earpiece. I also know that, once the shadow-clones are **cancelled** the original user will get its experience.

Comment: Yamato can make plant based bug, i guess Hashirama have something more powerful/effecient

Answer (score 2):

To understand this you need to dive a bit deeper into the wood style cloning technique

> A clone that is created by using chakra to alter the user's own cells into vegetation. The clones can be as simple in function as a wooden dummy for use in the Body Replacement Technique or completely mobile and able to perform techniques. They have the ability to travel far from the user and are able to communicate with the original. [source](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Wood_Clone_Technique)

Depending on how complicated you make the wood clone yourself it will even be able to communicate. Yamato also should be able to communicate with his wood clone, although this might be harder for him as he does have some of hashiramas cells. But is not as strong/ chakra rich as him

> Because they share the same cells, Yamato is able to track its location, communicate with it over long distances, and absorb any information it has gathered by laying his hand on it. Yamato can also use a seed form variant to this technique that operates in the same way: he is able to track anyone that he plants the seeds on by its response to his chakra. [source](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Yamato)

Comment: What they mean by communicate here? Telepathy based complete communication(like yamanaka clan's) or just sharing current location?

Comment: Also, the link you provided says even Yamato can communicate with his clones just like hashirama. It doesn't talk about any cell based problems.

Comment: @RikuduSennin There is not directly stated how they do communicate but as it is a direct clone build up of your own cells telepathy is most likely. As for the cells part I stated he has the hashirama cells. but not the same mana resevoir which might make it harder on him to maintain more complicated wood clones.

Comment: I know that yamato has hashirama's cells in his body (Thanks to orochimaru's experiments). My question is, the wiki says that Yamato also can communicate with his clones without mentioning anything about the communication limits(just sharing location or telepathy or something else).

Comment: @RikuduSennin as specified on the wiki although it does not properly explain  "Because they share the same cells, Yamato is able to track its location, communicate with it over long distances" It is due to the fact they share the same cells that they can communicate. With the most plausible way being telepathy but it only states they can comunicate due to having the same cells.